# nginx несколько доменов на один сайт

Tags: linux, сервер, nginx, домен

Как правильно сделать так, что бы несколько доменов вели на один сайт, и в браузере отображался тот домен, который ввел пользователь?
Т.е. при вводе в строку браузера например mydomen1.ru, mydomen2.ru, 192.168.1.10 пользователь заходил на один и тот же сайт, но в строке браузера отображался тот домен или ip, который он ввел

```
upstream php-handler {
server 127.0.0.1:9000;
#server unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
```

}

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomen1.ru;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;  # enforce https
}
```

Сейчас, если я зайду на 192.168.1.10, меня перенаправляет на mydomen1.ru

Comment: Разве за это не DNS отвечает? (Ключевые слова: DNS, баланс нагрузки)

Answer (score 1):

В директиве server_name перечислить доменные имена.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomen1.ru mydomen2.ru "";

    location / {
    }
}
```

Описание директивы [server_name](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server_name).